# ionCube - Works on CLI but not with HTTP

Tags: apache-http-server, yum, centos-5

*-- I've tried this question [on server fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/274940/ioncube-works-on-cli-but-not-with-http) without much success, maybe i'll be more lucky here, I'll delete the original if I can get an answer here --*

I'm trying to install ionCube loader on a CentOS 5 machine.

I've installed php 5.3 & ionCube loader through the atomic yum repo.

when i check on the command line, php says ionCube loads fine:

```
php -v
PHP 5.3.6 (cli) (built: Apr 19 2011 12:28:40) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2011 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.0.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2011, by ionCube Ltd.
```

but the loader isn't picked up when I run a php script via http (?)

phpinfo() shows in the "Additional .ini files parsed" that /etc/php.d/ioncube.ini is indeed loaded and parse but ionCube doesn't work; ionCube encrypted files are shown as is rather than parsed and the phpinfo page shows no mention of ionCube (apart from the parsed ini file).

The ioncube.ini file content is:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so
```

I've restarted apache. Tried zend gard loader and it worked right away. ionCube does not. Weird

What's missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, worked it out.. SELinux was the problem.

This webpage has a great description of the problem and info on how to fix it:

http://blog.maurus.be/index.php/2011/02/ioncube-on-a-selinux-enabled-server/

*The only slight difference for me was that the audit log is /var/log/audit/audit.log and not /var/log/audit.log*